# My applications shortcuts aren't up to date in the start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, search-indexing

I have an indexation issue with application shortcuts, some removed applications still appear while some installed are simply not in the start menu.

In the Indexation option window I have the start menu, so I tried the link to solve issues of search and indexation, then I got an error message that tell me that my authorizations are incorrect on folders of search service of Windows.

Windows doesn't seems to be able to automatically fix that issue.

Does someone know how to do it manually?

The folder on which the issue is: C:\Users\Flamaros\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Apparently the System user can't access it, but he have Full control on this folder tree

Comment: Is that normal that "c:\Users\All Users" and "c:\ProgramData" are the same folders? One seems to be a link to the other one.